# Cycling Digits puzzle

Tags: puzzle, recreational-mathematics

I'm trying to answer the following:

"I have in mind a number which, when you remove the units digit and place it at the front, gives the same result as multiplying the original number by $2$. Am I telling the truth?"

I think the answer to that is no. It's easy to prove that it's false for numbers with two digits: Let $N = d_0 + 10 \cdot d_1$. Then $2N = 2 d_0 + 20 d_1$ and the "swapped" number is $N^\prime = d_1 + 10 d_0$. We would like to have $2d_0 + 20 d_1 = d_1 + 10d_0$ which amounts to $8d_0 = 19d_1$. The smallest value for which this equality is fulfilled is $d_0 = 19, d_1 = 8$ but $19$ is not $\leq 9$ that is, is not a digit, hence there is no solution.

Using the same argument I can show that the claim is false for $3$-digit numbers.

I conjecture that it's false for all numbers. How can I show that? Is there a more general argument than mine, for all numbers? Thanks for helps.

Comment: Zero respects the constraint, but it's a bit a dull solution

Comment: Does the number have to be in base 10? Does it matter?

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes the number is assumed to be in base $10$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you follow your argument but let $N=a+10b$ where $a$ is a single digit but let $b$ have $n$ digits, then $2N=10^na+b$ and you get $b=\frac {10^n-2}{19}a$  If $n=17$, this is integral.  Then $a$ has to be at least $2$ to make $b$ have $17$ digits.  The smallest solution is $105263157894736842$

Another way to get there is to just start multiplying.  If you guess that the ones digit is $2$, you double it the ones digit of the product will be $4$, which will be the tens digit of the first number, and so on.  Stop when the product starts with a $2$ and doesn't carry.  You get $$105263157894736842 \\ \underline {\times\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2} \\ 210526315789473684$$  If you had started with a $1$, you would miss the leading zero.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Comment: @Ross Millikan: a) how did you get the $b = \frac{10^n-2}19a$? b) By "this is integral" you mean an integer number? c) In the multiplication approach how did you figure out that when you reach $57894736842$ you had to place the carry $1$ in front i.e. $157894736842$ instead of the $0$ which would match the number after multiplication and keep the carry? Great answer by the way!

Comment: @Jim:  a)I substituted $N=10b+a$ into $2N=10^na+b$ and solved for $b$.  b) Yes c) When I am there I have a carry coming in, so $2 \cdot 5 +1=11$ and I write down $1$ and carry $1$.  Then the $1$ goes on top and I do $2 \cdot 1 +1=3$.  I stop when I get a $2$ in the product with no carry.

Comment: @RossMillikan: How did you figure out the number from the equation? If I use $n = 17$ as you mention (how did you come up with that?) I get $\frac{10^{17}-2}{19} = 99999999999999999.894736842105.....$ and not an integer. So I am lost in your next comment `Then  has to be at least 2 to make  have 17 digits...`

Comment: @Jim:  $\frac {10^{17}-2}{19}=5263157894736842$.  I don't know where your value comes from, but it is wrong.  The division clearly should not give a value near a power of $10$ because of the division by $19$.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I just passed $10^{17}−2÷19$ to an online calculator and got that https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculator-precision.html

Comment: @RossMillikan: You are right, I used another calculator and got the number you mention. How did you come up with 17 as an exponent?

Comment: @Jim:  I just made a spreadsheet with powers of $10 \pmod {19}$ and looked for $2$.  $10^{17}$ will probably overflow, but you can multiply the previous value by $10$ and then take $\bmod 19$  When you did $10^{17}-2 \div 19$ it properly divided $2$ by $19$ first, then subtracted from $10^{17}$ as the order of operations requires.  The stacked fraction puts parentheses around the $10^{17}-2$.  That is the difference.

Comment: @RossMillikan: $10^{17} mod 19 = 2$ and $(10^{17} - 2) mod 19 = 0$. I still don't get how you connected it to using it to get an integer? Is $17$ the only exponent that results in $2$?

Comment: We need $\frac {10^n-2}{19}$ to be an integer.  $n=17$ is the smallest exponent that gives an integer.  You can add any multiple of $18$ to it and get another one.  Make a spreadsheet as I suggested and see.

Comment: @RossMillikan: 1) I did make and spreadsheet and I do see that for $n=15$ mod is $8$ for $n=16$ mod is $4$ and for $n=17$ mod is $2$. So minus 2 would be an integer since the remainder is 0. Got it! Why did you say do a spreadsheet with with powers of 10(mod19)? I used a small program for that and I could also have tried all divisions with 19 and see which one was an integer. What is the difference in the 2 methods?

Comment: @RossMillikan: 2) `Then  has to be at least 2 to make  have 17 digits.` If I multiply the result of $\frac{10^{17}-2}{19}$ with $2$ I get $10526315789473684$ which is 17 digits. But how did you think about appending $2$ to the end of it for the solution?

Comment: I used a spreadsheet because I find it easier than writing a program.  When I do program, it is Python, which as arbitrary sized integers, but spreadsheets do not so you have to use $\bmod$ along the way to keep the numbers to reasonable size.  If $a=1$ and you do the same division you only get a $16$ digit result, so that doesn't work.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I got why $a$ has to be at least $2$ but the result is the prefix of the final solution $10526315789473684$. How did you notice that by appending $2$ you get the solution? I am having trouble connecting that part together

Comment: That is in the problem and in the definition of $a$ and $b$.  We said $N=10b+a$.  That comes from writing $b$ and then $a$.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Ah I see, you plugged it in the original definition. Wow! That is very smart! Thank you very much for explaining this to me

Answer (score 3):

**The number has to be divisible by 9**

The remainder left by a number when divided by $9$ is equal to the sum of its digits. Now, here, you are not changing the digits when transferring the digits, so the remainder does not change. However, multiplying by two should double the remainder module nine and this is a contradiction unless the number is divisible by $9$.

---

**Solution**

Assume that the number $u = 9k$ and the representation of $u$ is $$\overline{a_{n}a_{n-1}\ldots a_{1} a_{0}} = u = 9k$$. Then $$\overline{a_{0}a_{n}\ldots a_{2} a_{1}} = 2u = 18k$$.

Hence multiplying by 10 we get,
 $$\overline{a_{0}a_{n}\ldots a_{2} a_{1}} * 10 + a_{0} = 180k + a_{0}$$.

Regrouping the digits and then writing the original number as $9k$, we get

$$a_{0}*10^{n+1} +  \overline{a_{n}a_{n-1}\ldots a_{1} a_{0}}= 180k + a_{0}$$

which implies that

\begin{align}
&a_{0}*10^{n+1} +  9k = 180k + a_{0}\\ \\
&\left(10^{n+1} -1 \right) a_{0} = 171k\\ \\
&\underbrace{\overline{99\ldots999}}_{n+1}a_{0} = 171k
\end{align}

that is $$171k = 9*\left( \underbrace{\overline{11\ldots111}}_{n+1}\right) a_{0}$$

hence $$19k = \left( \overline{11\ldots 111}\right) a_{0}$$

So, the problem comes down to finding the solutions of the above equation.

Combinining this with Ross Millikan's Analysis, we get the equation

$$ 10^{n+1} = 171k + a_{0}$$ 
and 
$$ 9k \equiv a_{0} \, \mathrm{ mod } \, 10$$

Comment: But you have the solution $2\cdot 0=0$, so this argument only shows that the sum of digits must be divisible by 9.

Comment: Unless the number was a multiple of 9 to begin with

Comment: @PerManne Yup. Sorry about that, I was going to update it.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand what you do below the line (in particular not how you conclude that all the digits are ones) but arguing using remainders hadn't occurred to me and it's very interesting to see a new piece of information.

Comment: Added some more explanation. I hope it is more clear now.